# How to call actions between classes?

Tags: iphone, linker

yeah it's me again :)

I've got a little problem.

I've got a custom cell with a TextField. I want the keyboard to hide when i tap "done"

so normally i do this jus with `[sender resignFirstResponder]`.

In this case that doesn't work because the custom cell is a class itself and has its own .h and .m files.

How is it possible to link something like that in general?

Comment: You question does not make any sense. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

Set your UITextField's delegate to the UIViewController. You can do this in Interface Builder (if you created your UITableViewCell like that), or through code (in your UIViewController).

```
tableViewCell.textView.delegate = self
```

Now, in your UIViewController, add this function:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  return NO;
}
```

This code hasn't been tested, but it should probably work.